# NFC Receive NDEF tags from Android 2.3.3

Tags: java, android, nfc, android-beam, ndef

I have been developing an Android application which sends NDEF messages via Android Beam and a desktop application which receives them.

Everything works as expected; however, I personally believe that the Android Beam "Tab to beam"-screen is too circumstantial. I know it is not possible to suppress the "Beam-Screen". 
I wan´t to create an application, which is able to receive simple NDEF tags from my Android mobile (sent with NfcAdapter.enableForegroundNdefPush() ).

could anyone give me some clues to achieve that? is there a package i could use? i tried to use .net but there is no API for it. I would prefer java.

Hardware: 4.0.4 Android. ACR122 nfc reder/writer.

Any suggestions would help me.

Thanks in advance
MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

http://code.google.com/p/ismb-npp-java/wiki/NppFromACR122ToPhone

That worked for me! it is not realy stable but it works....
I created a GUI and fused the two main classes. I am able to send and receive with one application now.

Beware! ics (ice cream sandwich) has problems with recognizing simple NDEF actions. I used 2.3.3.

http://www.nfcrumors.com/12-16-2011/ice-cream-sandwich-bug-nfc-tag/

If you want to use NFC with Android 4.0.x you should use Android Beam (from google) it was a lot easier to implement.

Regards